# Connection failed: could not find driver and PHP error startup if uncomment the driver

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to MSSQL server for my application with PHP. Here is what I do:

1- The code:

```
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'sqlsrv:dbname=Help;host=localhost';
$user = 'help';
$password = 'XXXXXXX';

try {
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

/* select all the weekly tasks from the table googlechart */
$result = $dbh->query(" SELECT CASE WHEN SOLSTATUS = 1 THEN 'Em andamento' When SOLSTATUS = 5 THEN 'Aguardando' when SOLSTATUS = 0 then 'Não iniciado' ELSE 'Outro' END as StatusChamado, count(*) as Quantidade from solicitacao (nolock)
where solstatus not in (7,9)
and UsuIDResponsavel = 2721184
group by solstatus ");
```

2-Using this without any modifications at php.ini I got the error could not find the drive.

3- If I change the php.ini (removing the comment of php mssql) and adding the PHP drivers downloaded from Microsoft and located at xampp/php/ext the APACHE doesn't start and keep saying "PHP STARTUP ERROR".

I really don't know how to fix this and make this thing to work with the MSSQL.

Comment: The `php.ini` file is for [PHP configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) but the code you posted is PHP code. That would go in a `.php` file.

Comment: Yeah I Know. Lol. There are two things different. I just posted the code to check if evertyhing with the syntax are okay. But I really know that the problem is with the drivers and dll's at PHP.ini